# Perl shortcuts "$/" and "$\"

Tags: perl

I am confused by the perl shortcuts as to how they are used exactly.
I am much more confused about the variables `$/` and `$\`.
Can you please help me in this as I am new to perl scripting.

Comment: See http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html

Answer (score 7):

For `$/`: It is the input separator. When you read from an input source (e.g. a file) with `my $line = <FILEHANDLE>` then Perl will read as much data from the file until it encounters the content of `$/`. It therefore defaults to the newline character `"\n"` which gives us the normal understanding of what a line is.

However, when you unset `$/` then Perl will read the whole input stream in one call. It's therefore a common idiom to unset `$/` locally and read the whole file, e.g.

```
my $whole_file = do {
  local $/;
  <FILE_HANDLE>
};
```

or something similar.

`$\` on the other hand is always appended after each call to `print`. It is by default undefined, meaning you have to add things like newline characters yourself.

All those things are explained in detail in the [perlvar documentation page](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html).

Comment: Thanks for sharing the documentation Link...:)

Comment: `$/` is also what is removed by `chomp`, which can be a finer point worth remembering.